# Regarding music: "in a track" or "on a track"

Tags: prepositions

Is it

- 1.1 "it doesn't matter if you hear it on rap tracks"
- 1.2 "it doesn't matter if you hear it in rap tracks"

Would it be different if I use "song" instead?

- 2.1 "it doesn't matter if you hear it on rap songs"
- 2.2 "it doesn't matter if you hear it in rap songs"

My gut feeling says "on" is correct, with 2.2 allowed colloquially

Comment: I think I would use “on tracks” and “in songs”

Answer (score 1):

My instinct would be to use "in", since such usage is common with other forms of art:

> I read it in a book.
>   I heard it in a song.
>   I saw it in a picture.

Modern media has confused things, though:

> I read it on my iPad.
>   I heard it on the radio.
>   I saw it on TV.

However:

> I saw it in a movie.

All of these usages are colloquial, and using "in" instead of "on", and vice versa, would not work. As for "I heard it in/on a music track?", go with your instincts.

Comment: I don't see a contradiction in the second set. Book, song, and picture are pieces of art whereas iPad, radio and TV are platforms. Of course, I might say "on a TV program"

Comment: So then by that logic, with a song being a piece of art, we should use in?  That was also my inclination.  "I heard it in a song."

Comment: But then there's "I read it on EL&U Stack Exchange"...